# uinavigation bar in all view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

In my project the navigation bar is being coming only in rootview(homeview) for the first only,i want to enable navigation bar in all views?Here my code?What change should i do for that

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.window.rootViewController =navigationController;
[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Please help me to code?

Comment: How are you go from viewController2 to another viewControllers?

Comment: from viewController2 im having buttons,using buttons only.Not only im using navigation bar in other views as IB,i want navigation bar programmatically in every view .how can i? @Padavan

Comment: Do you use something like this to go to another viewControllers? [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO]; in your viewController2 ?

Comment: No ,im using like dis `about *scraping=[[about alloc]initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:scraping animated:YES];`@Padavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in a delegate class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Set the navigation controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-uinavigation-to-simple-view.html)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:NO];  

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And when you navigate to the another view from viewController2 do pushViewController not others like presentView

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How did you go to the next view from viewController2? you should use pushViewController

Comment: its working with pushViewController,i used presentViewController.thanks alot mate

Comment: from navigation view other view its working properly but if am goin to other view using uibutton its not working,Here what should i do @Neo

Comment: are you using storyboard? have you set the button using interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable navigation in all the views then you will have to declare the navigation in AppDelegate.m wherein it will be viewable in all the views. I dont have my mac rite now but its the best advice I can provide for now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.window.rootViewController =navigationController;
[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Change the uiviewcontroller to SecondViewController

Comment: Now also its coming in first time only @AppleDelegate

Answer (score 0):

try this way may be helped you

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1]; // simulate waiting for server response

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    // Initialise the navigation controller with the first view controller as its root view controller

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    // This is where we hide the navigation bar! :)

    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    // Navigation controller has copy of view controller, so release our copy



    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];


    [self.viewController release];
    // Add the navigation controller as a subview of our window

    [_window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: No ,its not working,its coming only for the first time @Vikas Rajput

Comment: it's code work for me current time , can you say which xcode you work now.

Comment: Same here but my code run correct , please check root view and another views , where you hide the navigationController.